# Creating a button grid

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm sorry, I'm asking such a stupid question, but I can't do something and it really annoys me. Actually, I'm trying to do exactly what is written in one tutorial, but probably I didn't copy the code right.
What I'm trying to do is a 4x4 grid of buttons using table layout.
Here is my xml activity:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
          <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:id="@+id/Field"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
          </TableLayout>`

and here is my java code:

```
    public class Pokus extends Activity{

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TableLayout field = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.Field);
        Button but[][] = new Button[4][4];
        for(int i = 1; i!=5; i++){
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
            for(int r = 1; r!=5; r++){
                tr.addView(but[i][r]);
            }
            field.addView(tr);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pokus);
}}
```

Does anybody understand, where is the mistake?

Comment: You may also run into an `OutOfBounds`-exception since array-indices start with `0`. Your example creates arrays wich have indices from `0` to `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the content view before you do anything else. This should go in the beginning of the `onCreate` method:

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_pokus);
```

The commenter above is also right; start `i` at 0:

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        for(int r = 1; r<4; r++){
            tr.addView(but[i][r]);
        }
        field.addView(tr);
    }
```

`Button but[][] = new Button[4][4];`
-- You have not initialized the buttons in your array. Go through it iteratively first with this before the loop you wrote:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        but[i][j] = new Button();
```

This will solve your `NullPointerException`.

^ Instead of doing all this though, just don't use an array at all and simply say:

```
for(int i = 0; i<4; i++){
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        for(int r = 1; r<4; r++){
            tr.addView(new Button()); // new Button() instead of but[i][j]
        }
        field.addView(tr);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.

Comment: Still I have a small problem-I have an error. The logcat says, the problem is in the row"tr.addView(but[i][r]);"

Comment: 02-13 13:29:44.444: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3353)
02-13 13:29:44.444: E/AndroidRuntime(1831):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3336)

Comment: What is the specific exception?

Comment: 02-15 05:25:34.684: E/AndroidRuntime(1899): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.makor.pokus/com.makor.pokus.Pokus}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: That's because when you declare a `new Button[][]` you are only initializing the array. However, you did not initialize your individual buttons inside the array, so the elements in it are 'null' references. That's why the 'NullPointerException' is thrown. When you initialize each individual button, it is given a reference.